# Moneybookers response is a GET instead of a POST

Tags: payment

I have implemented Moneybookers to our site.

The request is fine, the payment goes to our Moneybookers account, the money is debited from the user's account.

The response URL is https://example.com/finance/responsemoneybookers

The problem:

-After payment, the user click Confirm, and the user is being redirected to https://example.com/finance/responsemoneybookers

Moneybookers should POST the transaction data so we can validate it, but instead of POST, it just make a standard GET request with no data. What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
<input id="status_url" name="status_url" type="hidden" value="https://example.com/finance/responsemoneybookers" />
```

to your form